# Android R namespacing resources

Tags: android, resources, namespaces

I was wondering if there is any way to "namespace" resources using Android's R. Currently, creating a layout called "home.xml" will generate R.layout.home, which is convenient for referencing in the code. It seems like this could get messy with larger scale applications. I've been looking around to see if there is a way to organize resources such that they could be referenced in the code with "namespaces" (ie. R.layout.home.main).

If it isn't possible to do this, is there any reasonable explanation as to why it can't be done?

Comment: "seems like this could get messy with larger scale applications" can you elaborate this.

Comment: If there are, say, 100 different layouts then the folder containing the 100 layouts would be "messy" because it is likely that the layouts can be categorized. My biggest concern is that this can be difficult to organize.

Comment: No. All res/* folders must have linear structure. I cannot tell you why, but it _seems_ like a requirement. On a side note, your assets folder can have sub-folders. To add a bit of structure, name your layout files like `home_main`, `home_secondary`, `home_tertiary` etc.

Comment: @Patrick : If you've got 100 different layouts then your design approach is messy from the start. You can, on the other hand, create projects and export them as JARs each with their own resource folders then all you do is add them to your main project. Each resource needs to have a unique name however but as long as you import the relevant R class in any class which needs the resources, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

But you could name layout file ie. home_main, home_sth_else